# Recursively open all folds in current open fold?

Tags: folding

If I am in an open fold containing closed folds, how do I recursively open all those closed folds?

I kind of thought this would be the use-case for `zO`, but it seems `zO` only works when the fold is already closed. Is a better way to accomplish this than closing and re-opening the current fold recursively (`za zA`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's anything shorter than `zczA`. That's pretty easy and probably what I'd do. I guess you could shorten it a bit with a mapping ;)

```
:nnoremap <leader>O zczA
```

But let's say you absolutely can't or don't want to close the already open fold. This is what I came up with...

---

It's not a Normal mode command but from the command line `foldopen` might do what you want...

```
:{range}foldo[pen][!]
```

Let's say you have folds like this...

```
10: F1<
+1: ...
+2: F1.1>
??: ...
??: F1.1.1>
??: ...
+3: ...
+4: F1.2>
```

Here `<` indicates an open fold, `>` closed. `F1` is an open fold at line 10. `F1.1` is a closed fold nested inside `F1` that starts +2 lines down. `??` indicates that we can't currently see that line.

If you're on line 10 then this will open `F1.1`:

```
:+2foldo
```

Add a bang, `:+2foldo!` and it will operate recursively so `F1.1.1` will open as well. With range `+4` you'll also open `F1.2` as well as any folds nested inside it (if you are using `!`).

Hope that makes sense. Play around with it. Note the close equivalent; it is the same format with name `foldc[lose]`.

If you're using the Marker type of folds (surrounded with `{{{` and `}}}`) then an alternative is to go the end of the first line of the open fold of interest, put the cursor on one of the three `{`, hit `V%` which will select everything inside the fold and then hit `zO` for recursive open.

None of this is as nice as a simple, short Normal mode key sequence...perhaps someone knows folds better than me and has a better idea...but you could use a mapping to keep it in Normal mode. I haven't tested this yet but I'm thinking along the lines of:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <leader>zO ':+' . v:count1 . 'foldo!<CR>'
```

So Normal mode sequence `2\zO` should do the same as `:+2foldo!`.

**Update:** @ropeladder has a Normal/Visual mode command that doesn't require closing the outer fold first:

- `]z` : jump to end of current open fold
- `<s-v>` : (Shift-V) start linewise visual mode
- `[z` : jump to beginning of current open fold
- `zO` : recursively open all folds that are visually selected

Of course, it'd be much easier to close the outer fold first and use `zczA` but since this doesn't close first and isn't on the command line I figured I'd note it. (And bonus points for `]z`/`[z`.)

Comment: How about `]z<shift-v>[zzO`? That should automatically select the entire contents of the current partially-open fold, and then open them recursively.

Comment: @ropeladder A little long but clever enough to merit a mention in my answer. :)